# Is there a Java JSON library that uses the same pattern as XMLEncoder

Tags: java, json, serialization

I have looked at a few JSON libraries for Java, but few of them seem to follow the same serialization pattern as core Java serialization patterns.  I would like to use a native Java JSON serialization object, but in the absence of that what third party library matches Native serialization and preferably will serialize anything marked serializable.

Comment: Quick question: what do you mean by pattern? Structure of the format produced, or usage pattern (how to call)? Or perhaps feature set offered?

Comment: By pattern I mean the general flow of in put and out put.  for instance the XML serializer in Java takes a POJO an writes and XML file or Reads an XML file and produces a POJO.  Most Java serialization functions follow the same Pattern of creating an POJO from a serialized file or taking a POJO and serializing it o a file.

Most of the third party JSON libraries do not work this way, which is rather silly since JSON is object notation.

Answer (score 1):

best I have seen on paper is [flexJSON](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) it looks fairly complete and a very close match to the XMLEncoder pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty fond of the [Jackson JSON Processor](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).  Its fast, and very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at google's [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) ? It will serialize any POJO hierarchy very nicely for you.